# A Django QuerySet of recent Tweets favorited by a group of Users?

Tags: django, django-models

I'm modelling Tweets and the Users who posted them. A User can also favorite any of the Tweets (posted by other Users):

```
class Tweet(models.Model):
    ...
    user = models.ForeignKey('User')

class User(models.Model):
    ...
    favorites = models.ManyToManyField(Tweet, related_name="favoriting_users")
```

I'm struggling with how to make a QuerySet that will fetch all Tweets favorited by a particular group of Users. ie, if I did something like:

```
users = User.objects.filter(is_verified=True)
```

how would I get a list of recent Tweets favorited by any one of `users`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You know when you ask a question and then only minutes later find the answer?

```
users = User.objects.filter(is_verified=True)
tweets = Tweet.objects.filter(favoriting_users__in=users)
```